# how to retain checkbox status during pagination in struts

Tags: checkbox, tags, pagination, state

i am developing web application in struts 1.3 i am using display tag to display data i have checkbox in table display.i am   new in dispaly tag, pagination all I want to maintain the state of checkboxes across pages. What happens is when i check one checkbox and then go to say 2nd page then check one checkbox there and when i return to previous page the checked box is again unchecked. Means the status of the checkbox is not maintained.If it is maintained then it should show checked. when i goto next or previous page my action class is called everytime

i am not understanding how handle this . Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, solving this problem has several ways if struts framework does not provide the feature.

1. pass the checked value to page2 and pass back when switch from page2 to page1.
2. save the checked value in cookie and add code in page1 to reload the checked value in cookie.
3. save the checked status in server session.

Hope it would be helpful to you.